# Uploading excel sheet to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am developing a web application using php and bootstrap.Uploading an excel sheet  is one of the requirements of my application.Now i am partially implemented it (extract the data from excel sheet),the next thing i want upload these data into database table but failed.Here is my code

```
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$row=1;

while (($Data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    echo $Data[0];
}
fclose($file);
```

Here is the output of `$Data[0]`

[image]

I want to store the data in database table with these  fields .How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can start learning here: http://codular.com/php-mysqli OR
 http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage#connect-to-database OR you can easily search in google.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code of how you should do it . details can be found [here](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-read-excel-file-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php_609.html) .
Excel reader library will Handel most of the hustle for you

```
 ini_set("display_errors",1);
    require_once 'excel_reader2.php';



$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("example.xls");

echo "Total Sheets in this xls file: ".count($data->sheets)."<br /><br />";

$html="<table border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
{
if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
{
echo "Sheet $i:<br /><br />Total rows in sheet $i  ".count($data->sheets[$i][cells])."<br />";
for($j=1;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
{
$html.="<tr>";
for($k=1;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells][$j]);$k++) // This loop is created to get data in a table format.
{
$html.="<td>";
$html.=$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][$k];
$html.="</td>";
}

$html.="</tr>";
}
}

}

$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
echo "<br />Data Inserted in dababase";
?>
```

Comment: here is the error `Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\excel_reader2.php on line 844`  i am getting

Comment: download that source code http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-read-excel-file-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php_609.html and see if this runs then let me know

Comment: preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), in the library .. This will work just change this in the library . you have a newer php version that's the problem

Comment: I am getting the answer but some errors `Use of undefined constant cells - assumed 'cells' in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelphp\index.php on line 16`

Comment: `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelphp\excel_reader2.php on line 916

Notice: iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelphp\excel_reader2.php on line 1718`

Comment: Also i am getting these `iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\excelphp\excel_reader2.php on line 1718`